# Могу ли я использовать переменные LESS в "обычном" CSS-коде?

Tags: css, less

Закончил курс LESS, весьма заморочен, все в голове еще не устоялось, но хотелось бы уже понемногу себя приучать писать через LESS. Могу ли я объявлять переменную типа @color = #1bbc22c; и потом юзать этот цвет через переменную, поймут ли бровзеры?

Если нет, то как этот LESS подключить?

Comment: вы википедию не смотрели, по LESS ? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LESS_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9)  там даже написано как подключается ...

Comment: `LESS` не подключать а компилить в `CSS` надо. Хоть у них и есть браузерный js компилятор, но это не лучшее решение.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, переменные `LESS` `CSS` не поймет , но можешь воспользоваться родными переменными `CSS`

```css
:root {
  --color-blue: #2437e2;
}

div {
  background-color: var(--color-blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">div</div>
<div class="div2">div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В CSS и без препроцессоров есть переменные [вот](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) или  [тут](https://frontender.info/css-variables-why-should-you-care/) вопрос только в том насколько старые браузеры вам надо поддерживать.